# jQuery window resize and less than certain width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have search a lot but couldn't find proper solution. I am going to element prepend/append to another element after certain width. But it works after resize browser only.

I have found this solution but [still not helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642424/js-or-jquery-or-window-resize-or-when-window-width-is-less-than-npx)

How can i achieve?

```js
$(window).on("resize", function(event){
  $vWidth = $(this).width();
  $('#test').html($vWidth)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: so what is the question? Do you want to make it work onload also?

Comment: yes, it should work on load and after refresh too :)

Comment: @Kumar what element you want to append or prepend can you please add that in your HTML?

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/oupsh3g9/
Now got solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the code to run when the page loads you can also have it triggered when the page is ready.

I would convert the relevant portion of your code into a `function` to avoid duplication of codes.

Demo working sample:
https://jsfiddle.net/j6nermyL/9/

**Sample JS code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    checkWidth();
});
$(window).on("resize", function(){
    checkWidth();
});


function checkWidth(){
    $vWidth = $(window).width();
    $('#test').html($vWidth);

    //Check condition for screen width
    if($vWidth < 700){
         $('#msg').html("Width: Less than 700");
    }else{
         $('#msg').html("Width: More than 700");
    }
}
```

**Sample HTML code:**

```
<div id="test">Test</div>
<br>
<div id="msg"></div>
```

- **Update:** I modified my JSFiddle with the check condition.
- **Update 2:** The width is now retrieved from `$(window)`

**Reference:**

- [jQuery Ready event](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)
- [API documentation for .ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: How can i make add condition if less than 700px

Comment: Cool
Thanks mate

Comment: @Kumar You can easily add a JS condition to check if it's 700px, I updated my code, check it out! https://jsfiddle.net/j6nermyL/7/

Comment: :) Thanks, if this solved your issue please mark my answer as the solution. Cheers!

Comment: Cheers... Thanks a lot again

Comment: Yea its working but there is getting width extra 17px maybe its scrollbar width so how can we fix exclude of scrollbar width for mobile?

Comment: I just updated the code to get width from `$(window)` instead of `$(this)`. As far as I know, jQuery width should not include scrollbars and the scrollbars on mobile OS is an actually overlay rather than eating into the page as desktop browsers do.

Answer (score 2):

To make it work on Load, try

```
$( window ).load(function() {
  // Run code
});
```

and on resize try

```
$(window).on("resize", function(event){
  $vWidth = $(this).width();
  $('#test').html($vWidth)
});
```

you can write the conditions like `$(window).width() < 700` inside the methods

Comment: Happy know it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `load`, if you want to do action on page load

Try this:

```js
$(window).on("resize", function(event){
  $vWidth = $(this).width();
  $('#test').html($vWidth)
});

$(window).on("load", function(event){
  $vWidth = $(this).width();
  $('#test').html($vWidth)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```